Are "http://www.something.com#" "http://www.something.com?????" valid?
Seemingly wrong URLs are parsed and validated by commonly used tools (java and apache).
Both Java URL and Apache Validator do parse and validate the URLs in the subject without error.
However, reading RFCs 1034, 1123, 1738 and 2396 I understood that they should not be valid, because even if '#' and '?' are considered part (or start) of the fragment or the query part, they must be separated from the domain name by '/'.
Am I reading RFCs correctly or the tools are wrong?
EDIT: Adding reasoning.
RFC#1738 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), section "3.3. HTTP":
...
   An HTTP URL takes the form:

      http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>

   where <host> and <port> are as described in Section 3.1. If :<port>
   is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
   allowed.  <path> is an HTTP selector, and <searchpart> is a query
   string. The <path> is optional, as is the <searchpart> and its
   preceding "?". If neither <path> nor <searchpart> is present, the "/"
   may also be omitted.
...

Taken with the part 3.1 of the same RFC (plus other mantioned RFCs define pretty much the same):
...
    host
        The fully qualified domain name of a network host, or its IP
        address as a set of four decimal digit groups separated by
        ".". Fully qualified domain names take the form as described
        in Section 3.5 of RFC 1034 [13] and Section 2.1 of RFC 1123
        [5]: a sequence of domain labels separated by ".", each domain
        label starting and ending with an alphanumerical character and
        possibly also containing "-" characters. The rightmost domain
        label will never start with a digit, though, which
        syntactically distinguishes all domain names from the IP
        addresses.

...

means that neither '#' nor '???' can be a part of domain name or port. Therefore it must be separated from it by "/" ('may be ommited' means that it may not if either query or fragment is present).

RFC 1122? Be liberal in what you accept

RFC#1122 has nothing to do with validating URLs has it?
I asked explicitly "Am I reading RFCs correctly or the tools are wrong?" that is the question for which I am expecting to have answer. Or, if you prefer to answer more in depth then the question (explicit) is in the subject - "are those URLs wrong or not?"

The most recent RFC for URI syntax is 3986 and that seems to be fine with your examples as far as I can tell.

What was confusing about The <path> is optional, as is the <searchpart> and its    preceding "?". If neither <path> nor <searchpart> is present, the "/"    may also be omitted.? It literally says the / may also be omitted. Parameter strings and fragments are always possible additions to a URL, why would they be forbidden?

@ElliottFrisch I read as "you can omit the '/' at the end if there is nothing behind it". Which means, as I mentioned, "if there is something behind the host, then it may not be omitted".

The only thing present is the "host". And then you linked to the definition of a fully qualified domain name - which is only used to resolve the host name to ip address. One is a set of rules for URLs. The other is a set of rules for DNS host names. Neither of the rules says anything about "behind".

@ElliottFrisch I meant only what you quoted in the comment. If **neither** <path> nor <searchpart> is present... means that in this case URL contains schema and/or authority only, correct? In other words, there is nothing after or "behind" this as URL parts are in specific order, correct? It also means, that only in this case "/" may be omitted.

@ElliottFrisch Second, RFC1738 says nothing about resolution. In fact there is not a single "resolve" word or derivatives in this spec. The "host" section talks about hostname syntax. And it states a strict set of characters allowed for it, which includes neither "?" nor "#".

@SamPam Exactly! The host name is thus terminated. And all of /, ? or # or any other invalid character according to RFC1738 is not part of the hostname - but is part of the URL sent to the remote server. Which was specified by the (possibly) RFC1738 host. It could be an IP address. Is your question about URLs or is it about hostnames?
